# Show that PA has a denumerable model that is not isomorphic to N

Tags: predicate-logic, metalogic

I know that PA has inifnitely many models that can satisfy itself, but how we do prove that it has one particular denumerable model that is not isomorphic to its standard interpretation *N*?

Answer (score 0):

Take any model of PA in a language $L$ (typically $(0, succ)$), call it $M$. Extend $L$ by a constant $c$ i.e., $L' = L \cup c$. Let $M'$ be an elementary extension of $M$ (a model which agrees with $M$) that also satisfies $\forall  n\, c > n$. Show that $M'$ is finitely satisfiable ($c$ only needs to be greater than finitely many numerals $n$). By compactness $M'$ is satisfiable. By Löwenheim-Skolem there is an elementary countable sub-model of $M'$, call it $M*$. By transitivity of elementarity $M*$ is an elementary extension of $M$ so is a model of PA, it is countable and it isn't isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ because there is no element $c \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\, c > n$.

Comment: Just to clarify the terminologies a bit: I assume "succ" refers to successor (S) and by what do you mean by transitivity of elementarity?

Comment: May I know what does 'n' refer to?

Comment: sorry I thought I replied to these, the idea of n is a natural number in the standard interpretation, technically here it is just an element of M our initial model. succ is successor S. By transitivity of elementarity I mean if M' is an elementary extension of M and M* is an elementary extension of  M' then M*  is an elementary extension of M, you can convince yourself of this from the definition that M' is an elementary extension M, which is that for every L (not L') sentence phi  M' satisfies phi iff M satisfies phi.